# Replace random characters in string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I'm trying to replace random strings characters with a a set amount of
a specific character (i.e: `"*"`), I'll explain more in the code below.

```js
/**
 * Returns a string with replaced amount of strings with a set string
 * @param {string} str The input
 * @param {number} amountToReplace The amount of letters you want to replace
 * @param {string} generalReplace The general letter to replace with
 * @returns {string} Returns a string with the string thats finished
 */

var str = 'thisisastring';
var amountToReplace = 5; 
var generalReplace = '*'

// Function over here, e.g. with the name replacer
var returnMe = replacer(str, amountToReplac
```

Sorry if the params sound confusing, I'm still new to them!!

So the string, `str` is the string that's the input the `amountToReplace` is the amount of letters you want to replace and the `generalReplace` is general character you want to replace with.

If the amount is `5`, the output I'm expecting is something like:

**original:** `thisisastring`
**output:** `th*s**as*ri*g`

The string that is returned is supposed to replace random parts in the string(but still do the amount that was inputted, instead of doing 5 replacers but returning 3 as common matches were found).

Thanks!

Comment: You want random replacement?

Comment: Yes, but also with a set amount of strings I want to replace with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The smallest (arguably simplest):

- Split the string into Array `[...str] // (is now an Array)`
- Loop inserting at random points an array with the replacer character like i.e: `["t", "h", "i", ["*"], "i", ["*"], ...`
- `continue` looping until `i` (the `amount`) is not `0` and until the current value at the iterating index is an Array.
- Once all done, since we have how a 2D array, use `Array.prototype.flat()` to make it one dimensional like i.e: `["t", "h", "i", "*", "i", "*", ...`
- and convert it back to String using `Array.prototype.join()`

```js
const replacer = (str, i, rep) => {
  if (!str) return;                      // Do nothing if no string passed
  const arr = [...str];                  // Convert String to Array
  const len = arr.length
  i = Math.min(Math.abs(i), len);        // Fix to Positive and not > len 
  while (i) {
    const r = ~~(Math.random() * len);
    if (Array.isArray(arr[r])) continue; // Skip if is array (not a character)
    arr[r] = [rep];                      // Insert an Array with the rep char
    --i;
  }
  return arr.flat().join("");
};


console.log(replacer("thisisastring", 5, "*"));
```

The above example is **battle-tested** and works amazingly even if:

- There's no string or it's empty
- The string contains already all asterisks `"*****"`
- The `amount` is greater then the string length
- The `amount` is a negative integer

### The longest:

- Generate an Array of *N* (`amountToReplace`) random unique integers
- Convert the input string to Array, iterate it replacing every character in that random index to the `generalReplace` "*" character

```js
/**
 * Create an array of unique integers
 * @param {Integer} len Array length
 * @param {Integer} max Max integer value
 * @returns {Array} Array of random Unique integers
 */
function genArrRandInt(len, max) {
  const nums = new Set();
  while (nums.size !== len) nums.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * max));
  return [...nums];
};

/**
 * Returns a string with replaced amount of strings with a set string
 * @param {string} str The input
 * @param {number} amountToReplace The amount of letters you want to replace
 * @param {string} generalReplace The general letter to replace with
 * @returns {string} Returns a string with the string thats finished
 */
function replacer(str, amountToReplace, generalReplace) {
  const strArr = [...str];
  const uniqueArr = genArrRandInt(amountToReplace, str.length);
  uniqueArr.forEach(i => strArr[i] = generalReplace);
  return strArr.join("");
}


const str = "thisisastring";
const amountToReplace = 5;
const generalReplace = "*";

// Function over here, e.g. with the name replacer
const returnMe = replacer(str, amountToReplace, generalReplace);
console.log(returnMe);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for being so detailed, params were extremely useful and descriptive, amazing in-depth answer!

Comment: @Jeffplays2005 you're welcome

Comment: @Jeffplays2005 there's another fix you could do in `genArrRandInt(len, max)` and that's to use `max = Math.min(len, max);` to prevent max being greater than the the string length - in case you used something like : `replacer("aaa", 5, "*")` since "aaa" is smaller in length than 5. Or you could do the same inside the `replacer` function.

Comment: I just wanted to mention, there was a really small minor mistake for the first example, instead of `return res.flat().join("");`, it would be `return arr.flat().join("");` as res is undefined!

Comment: @Jeffplays2005 thank you so much for the extra eye. Thought `arr` would be a better term than `res` and forgot to rename the latest one :D thank you

Comment: Thats all good! Thanks again for the detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

Code might be something like:

```js
function rand(min, max){
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
function randCharReplace(string, replaceWith = '*', replaceCount = 1){
  const a = string.split(''), m = a.length-1;
  const f = ()=>{
    return rand(0, m);
  }
  for(let i=0,r; i<replaceCount; i++){
    while(r === undefined || a[r] === replaceWith){
      r = f();
    }
    a[r] = replaceWith;
  }
  return a.join('');
}
console.log(randCharReplace('thisisastring',  '*', 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

A better efficient approach using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
function replacer(str, len = 0, generalReplacer) {
  const length = len > str.length ? str.length : len,
           set = new Set(),
           newStr = [];
  
  while (set.size !== length) {
    set.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length));
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    set.has(i) ? newStr.push(generalReplacer) : newStr.push(str[i]);
  }

  return newStr.join("");
}

console.log(replacer("thisisastring", 5, "*"));
console.log(replacer("thisisastring", 1, "*"));
console.log(replacer("thisisastring", 7, "*"));
```

Comment: `newStr.push("*")` should be `newStr.push(generalReplacer)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replacer(string, amount) {
    // If string contains all '*' return string
    if ([...string.matchAll(/\*/g)].length === string.length) {
        return string
    }
    // copy the ori string convert to array
    let res = [...string]
    let i = amount
    let e = ['*', ' ']
    // iterate amount times
    while (i >= 1) {
        // get random index in array
        const randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * string.length)
        // get char at index
        const randomChar = res[randomIdx]
        // check if it not '*' or ' '
        if (!e.includes(randomChar)) {
            // replace char with '*'
            res.splice(randomIdx, 1, '*')
            i--
        }
    }
    return res.join('')
}
```

You can try this.

Comment: `replacer("asdf", 3)` returns wrong results like `asd*`, `a*s*` instead of i.e: `*s**` and if the string is `replacer("***", 3)` we enter an infinite loop.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks you for pointing out the err. I edited my answer.